# what is the method for SparkSession to read csv file stored in AWS s3?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3

I would like to utilize functions from Apache Spark to extract CSV contents from my S3 bucket. Apparently using the content's url as a parameter in `DataFrameReader`'s `.csv()` method is not working (e.g. `sparkSession.reader().csv(...)`). It looks like I may have to use Java SDK to access the storage first and do some parsing to convert the data to Dataset type Anybody have and idea or any reference I can read? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function with Scala

```
def readCsv(url: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(url)
  }
```

url should be like this s3://your_backet/backet_with_csv/